# Delta to delta or delta to wye transformer

Tags: delta, y-to-delta, delta-to-y

I am going to feed 240Vac 1-phase into a rotary phase converter the resulting 240 3-phase needs to power two robot controllers, but the controllers require 200-230Vac 3-phase or 400 - 480Vac 3 phase. As seen in the image below, the connection to the 2 robots requires L1, L2, L3 and PE.

The rotary phase converter supplier is quoting their delta to delta / delta to wye isolation transformer. It appears that a delta to wye isolation transformer is ~$1400 instead of the ~$2800 transformer quoted by the rotary phase converters supplier. The robot manufacturer indicated **I need even leg-to-leg voltage** My question is: **do I actually need the delta-to-delta option, or can I just attach the L1, L2, L3 and PE and leave the wye's neutral unconnected?** I am nervous about frying the controller but if it is safe to go with a different supplier for the transformer to save $1400 dollars, I would prefer to do that.

I also have a question about the **implications of using an isolation transformer but still attaching a path to earth which is the ultimate path of neutral.** It seems like this connection makes the two circuits no longer isolated.

[image]

Comment: Your best option would seem to find out "your" robot controllers can be powered with 240 V (single phase) - while 2 kVA isn't mean, it still is reasonable. 2nd best may be swapping their power supplies. Else, you would need a converter from single phase to three phase, rotating or not.

Comment: Maybe I am concerned about something I don't need to be, but I don't like the idea of the harmonics from a non-rotary based single to three phase solution. this is me not knowing about the internal circuits of the robot's power tray, but it doesn't seem like a good idea to just feed one leg of a 3-phase system.